# How to copy only distinct elements from one arrayList to another ArrayList

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, foreach

I have an class called TwoNumbers that creates an object that holds two numbers. I created an ArrayList<> that contains this object and I wanted to copy these objects to an new ArrayList.

The problem is that I only want to copy distinct objects to a new ArrayList.
Java sees each object as distinct when numbers inside the object could be the same and I don't know how to stop it from copying every single object over.

Two objects contain two properties of num1 and num2 and these are read in from a fileReader.
So basically the data of each TwoNumbers object is:

```
1,2 
3,5
5,4
2,1 //accidentally repeated (2,1 means as 1,2)
4,6
1,2 //accidentlly repeated etc.
```

In my file reader in the main code I read in all these data like this and so I have the TwoNumbers in an ArrayList:

```
TwoNumbers TwoNumbers = new TwoNumbers(num1,num2); // where num's are the  data to create this object 
TwoNumbersArray.add(TwoNumbers);
```

For the method I was trying to add only distinct elements to a newArrayList when the element doesn't exist.

My TwoNumber class:
public TwoNumbers(int n1, int n2)

```
{
    if(n1 < n2 ){
        this.num1 = n1;
        this.num2 = n2;
    } else
    {
        this.num2 = n1;
        this.num1 = n2;
    }
}

public int getNum1()
{
    return num1;
}

public int getNum2()
{
    return num2;
}
```

My method that I tried to do is:

```
public void addNew2 (List<TwoNumbers> TwoNumbersArray, List<TwoNumbers> newArrayList){
        for (TwoNumbers e: TwoNumbersArray){
            for (int i = 0; i<TwoNumbersArray.size(); i++){
                if (e.getNum1() != newArrayList.get(i).getNum1() && e.getNum2() != newArrayList.get(i).getNum2()){
                    newArrayList.add(e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: This piece of code only works, because the questioner uses this if statement in his constructor:

```
if(n1 < n2 ){
    this.num1 = n1;
    this.num2 = n2;
} else {
    this.num2 = n1;
    this.num1 = n2;
}
```

---

I dont know if I understood your problem correctly, but try this method:

```
public List<TwoNumbers> doStuff(List<TwoNumbers> list) {
    List<TwoNumbers> returnList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        boolean flag = true;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < list.size(); j++) {
            if (list.get(i).getNum1() == list.get(j).getNum1() && list.get(i).getNum2() == list.get(j).getNum2()) {
                flag = false;
            }
        }

        if (flag) {
            returnList.add(list.get(i));
        }
    }
    return returnList;
}
```

This method will loop through the list and if the `flag` variable is set to false we know that the object is a duplicate, so we dont have to add it to `returnList`.

If you have further questions or if this didnt answer your question feel free to hit me up.

Comment: It worked really well but I'm very new to all this and would you be able to explain when it comes to these stuffs. Especially the loop within loops with the i and j is just really confusing to me. Also when I was implementing your solution, the line: list.sort(Comparator.comparing(TwoNumbers::getNum1)); doesn't work for me and I removed it completely so the code wasn't breaking when it runs. What does this part do?

Comment: I think I figured out why that line would break the code when you mentioned Lamda. I'm using Java 7 and it looks like lambda wasn't introduced until Java 8. There's one final problem I think that getting rid of it did, the output is disordered and so what would be a good simple method to put them numerically. Right now the TwoNumbers are printing out eg. 1,2    1,3    1,4   1,8 etc... It would be more neat if the 1,8 gets printed out before the 1,4.

Comment: @Qwisatz hey, I updated my answer, I noticed that the `Lambda expression` might actually not be necessary. What do you mean when you say it was broken? `Lambda expressions` were implemented in Java 8 and what this piece of code did was loop through your List variable `list` by using streams and afterwards comparing each element in this list with all other elements by doing a so called static method call `TwoNumbers:getNum1`. You should probably read up on this topic since lambda expressions can be pretty handy. In this case it wasnt needed tho.

Comment: @Qwisatz I would advise you to upgrade to Java 8, because lambdas would simplify this task a lot. You should  probably open another questions, since sorting has nothing to do with the original topic

Answer (score 1):

```
List<TwoNumbers> newList = oldList.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Since you guarantee in the constructor, smaller number will be in the number1 property.
In TwoNumbers class override these methods like below.

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + number1;
    result = prime * result + number2;
    return result;
}
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    TwoNumbers other = (TwoNumbers) obj;
    if (number1 != other.number1)
        return false;
    if (number2 != other.number2)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```